# .net Await with existing/old code

Tags: vb.net, async-await

I have an existing dll with functions that can take some time to retrieve customer data. Until now I've been using good old threading.thread.start methods to prevent the UI locking up, but I've been trying to get my head around the Await/Async methods in .net 4.5. 
Is there a simple way to create an Await wrapper around these functions? I can update the dll to 4.5 but cannot change the structure of the code itself. Everything I try results in an error of..
'Await requires that type 'Boolean' have a suitable GetAwaiter method'

Example code is....

```
    Public Async Function GetByID(id As Integer) As Task(Of Boolean)
        'serviceBase is a dll with a number of functions for getting
        'data that returns true when a customer object has been filled
        Return Await ServiceBase.GetCustomer(id)
    End Function
```

What I don't understand is if I could update GetCustomer in the ServiceBase then I'd have to mark that as Async and return a task(of Boolean). But then I get errors because GetCustomer has no need to use Await at any point - its a number of small processes that in total add up to a blocked UI.

Comment: Is the act of getting a customer actually an asynchronous operation? There is no point in making a synchronous method `Async`. could you show the code in GetCustomer instead, it's more interesting in this case.

Comment: An example of that function (a customer could have details on source A & C for example)
'   Public Function GetCustomer(id As Integer) As Boolean
            If GetFromSourceA(id) Then
                'do some work with customer and return true
            End If
            If GetFromSourceB(id) Then
                'do some work with customer and return true
            End If
            If GetFromSourceC(id) Then
                'do some work with customer and return true
            End If
            If IsNothing(customer) Then Return False
            Return True
        End Function'

Comment: What @kai means is that unless `GetCustomer` returns a Task, calling `Await GetCustomer` isnt' going to make it asynchronous automagically. `async/await` is syntactic sugar that makes *awaiting* easier for *already* asynchronous methods. Eg, if `GetCustomer` calls a web service, you could use `Await client.CallThatMethodAsync` to call a service method asynchronously and get the result instead of calling `client.CallThatMethod` synchronously. If it's a DB access method, you could use `ExecuteReaderAsync` instead of `ExecuteReader`

Comment: So then are we saying in the scenario I have the best method is to create a thread like I have been and that Await is not really suitable for this kind of scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the methods you want async wrappers for are not truly Asynchronous, for example, they're not really I/O, but instead long standing processes that block your UI on say a desktop application, just wrap the actual call to the dll method in Await Task.Run(Function() ServiceBase.GetCustomer(id)). If it's an asp.net application, allow the synchronous operation to be synchronous.

What you don't want to do is create a fake async wrapper and add it to your dll by calling Task.Run. If something is CPU bound and it's blocking your UI (desktop app), just call it with Task.Run in your specific application context, and don't create a fake async implementation in your dll. Here are some great resources by Stephen Cleary on the matter:

[Stephen Cleary's Blog on Task.Run](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html)

Comment: Perfect thanks, the main reason I didn't want to touch the DLL is I wanted to functions there to remain synchronous and it didn't feel right to change that. The resource confirms my thoughts this would be bad practice so changing to Async with Task.Run on the UI/Application side of the fence works nicely. I guess at the end of the day I've not really gained much other than having code that's much easier to understand/read - seeing as I'm re-writing some of this it seems like a worthwhile job.

Comment: Totally understand. I've recently worked through a desktop application in a similar sounding scenario.